# Clear column content in Excel table based on specific cell value

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-tables, isnullorempty

I have the following Table in my macro-enabled excel file,

Table1:

[image]

My goal is:

Before closing this workbook, I need to clear Column D content (shown as "Column 4" in the Table1), only where column D cells value = 999.
For example, looking at the screenshot above - cell content in D2 and in D4 must be cleared when "close workbook" event triggered.

Important - if user will create a new record(s) in this table, then  any new cell under Column D could have 999 value too. If a new record contains cell value = 999 in the Column D - it must be cleared!
Any new record where cell value = 999 in column D must be cleared!

See updated picture of what I expect -

cells D2, D4, and also D7 (after the new record created in this tbl) had 999 value and cleared:

[image]

Using the following vba code but it's not working:

```
     Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

        Dim sht As Worksheet
        Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        If Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Columns(4).Value = 999 Then
           Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Columns(4).ClearContents
  
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two immediate issues:

- A `ListObject` does not have a `Columns` property, rather a [`ListColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.listcolumns) property.
- Loop* over the cells in the `ListColumn.DataBodyRange` rather than attempting to compare the entire column to 999.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = Me.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In tbl.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange
        If cell.Value = 999 Then 
            cell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

<sup>* This can be made much faster using a `Variant` array but should be fine for a relatively small table.</sup>

Comment: @Hell-1931 - VBasic2008's answer is definitely better than this btw. `Range.Replace` should be faster than a loop. Go ahead and use it (even accept it too) instead of mine :-)

Comment: Sorry, I had to re enter my comment...
In my case I think - loop and referring to cell is better.
In this question I described only an example (a simplified model of the entire project)
I slightly modified it, added MsgBox and added the following line in your code
cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
so, now, after content clears, another part of my code is working prompting the workbook from being closed. And the entire row is highlighted - for user to delete it!

Comment: My workbook won't have too large number of records (not sure if it could create issue otherwise), but I think  using loop is fine

Answer (score 3):

### Clear Values in an Excel Table

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Me.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim lcl As ListColumn: Set lcl = tbl.ListColumns("Column 4") ' 4
        
    lcl.DataBodyRange.Replace 999, Empty, xlWhole
    
End Sub
```

### EDIT

- If you want to avoid the 'save alert dialog' when the workbook was already saved you can improve with the following:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Dim IsSaved As Boolean: IsSaved = Me.Saved
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Me.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim lcl As ListColumn: Set lcl = tbl.ListColumns("Column 4") ' 4
        
    lcl.DataBodyRange.Replace 999, Empty, xlWhole
    
    If IsSaved Then Me.Save
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I always forget about `Range.Replace` - this is much better than a loop. I'll blame it being quite late here :-)